# How to send dropdown selected value to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can i use dropdown selected value to asp.net mvc controller for filling another dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a handy blog post here regarding cascading dropdowns:

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-41-creating-cascading-dropdown-lists-with-ajax.aspx

I'd suggest using jQuery to return a JSON result from the controller with the data for the next dropdown. This isn't great for accessibility but even in WebForms Javascript is used to postback `DropDownList` controls anyway.